# Vim zebra line coloring?

Tags: colorscheme, plugin-system

Is there a plugin or way for me to alternate the background color for each line in vim?

E.g.

[image]

---

Previously I'd found [vim-zebra](https://github.com/dahu/vim-zebra) but this looks really ugly:

[image]

I'd prefer the whole line to be colored, not just a part of it.

Comment: AFAIK this is impossible.

Comment: @romainl why? I doubt it, plugins like `airline`/`powerline` manage to color entire lines.

Comment: No they don't. They colorize the status line and the tab line, which are *designed* to be colorized. Regular text lines are not designed to be colorized like that except for closed folds and the current line.

Comment: Note that you can change the colour of that vim-zebra plugin yourself with the `:highlight command`. The default is: `hi Zebra ctermbg=green guibg=green`

Comment: Looks like your issue with vim-zebra is that your vim background is transparent, using that of the terminal emulator behind it, which means that vim-zebra's green is stopping short, only going as long as the text because that's effectively where 'vim stops'.

Comment: @OliverFord and.. to fix?

Comment: @theonlygusti Depends on how your `colorscheme` is set. For example, I use `colorscheme solarized`, so I have `let g:solarized_termtrans=1` in my vimrc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible using my plugin [DynamicSigns](https://github.com/chrisbra/DynamicSigns). Quoting from the README:

> ### 2.7 Alternating colors
>
> You can also set up the plugin to color the lines in your buffer in alternating colors. To do so, set the
>   g:Signs_Alternate variable in your |.vimrc| like this:
>
> ```
> :let g:Signs_Alternate = 1
> ```
>
> This will display each even line nummer in one color and each odd line
>   number in a different color.
>
> Run :UpdateSigns or :Signs to update displaying the signs in your
>   buffer.

Comment: I was trying to come up with a solution but couldn't find a clever way to define my syntax group. In your plugin I've found where you [define the highlighting of the `LineOdd` and `LineEven` groups](https://github.com/chrisbra/DynamicSigns/blob/master/autoload/DynamicSigns.vim#L64-L103) but I couldn't find where you define theses groups patterns (with a `syntax match` or similar function) would you mind pointing me out to this place?

Comment: @statox, if you want to color the whole line even further than its contents, you need to use signs. Therefore, there is no syntax rule involed in that plugin but it uses only signs.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Oh I see, I'm not familiar with the signs I'll study your code to understand it better :-)

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Okay. It was this part that can be interpreted wrongly, then: "This will display each even line nummer in one color and each odd line number in a different color." Maybe it could be changed to something like: "This will display each evenly numbered line in one color..."?

Comment: Can I make it alternate the gutter too? SignColumn?

Comment: @theonlygusti no, you can only turn off the gutter column (`:h 'signcolumn'`)

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt  and coloring the numbers column in alternating bands? is that possible?

Comment: @theonlygusti no, you can only color it with one single color