# How do you change the background color for only one window?

Tags: highlight

I have tried ownsyntax but that does not work. I want do change the background color for only one window? I have tried this but it highlights all the windows.

```
hi Normal guibg=grey guifg=black
```

---

It looks like it is wincolor, not sure if there's another way to change without adding a group. Not sure why my answer of wincolor was deleted.

I am working on an Rgb colors plugin in which I need to be able to look at the random colors. I accomplish by using a popup window with wincolor which seems to to work fine. The colors are not fixed, I just used this dictionary to show as an example. If there are better solutions than mine I would appreciate a response.

```
let color_keys = keys(s:css_colors)
for index in range(0,len(color_keys) - 1 )
    let color = color_keys[index]
    let popid= Popup(color,60000, index * 4)
    let cmd = 'hi TEMPCOLOR' . color . ' guibg='.color.' | let &wincolor="TEMPCOLOR'. color. '"'
    call win_execute(popid,cmd)
endfor
```

[image]

Here is an example of one buffer in one color and another buffer in another color.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let color_keys = keys(s:css_colors)
for index in range(0,len(color_keys) - 1 )
    let color = color_keys[index]
    let popid= Popup(color,60000, index * 4)
    let cmd = 'hi TEMPCOLOR' . color . ' guibg='.color.' | let &wincolor="TEMPCOLOR'. color. '"'
    call win_execute(popid,cmd)
endfor
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

1. The answer is different for Vim and Neovim. Vim has `:h 'wincolor'` to overwrite "Normal" for a given window, while Neovim has `:h 'winhighlight'` to override any number of highlighting groups.
2. You can't really assign arbitary colors to anything except a highlighting group. But you're not obliged to create new groups if existing ones are okay. For example, `setlocal wincolor=PMenu` is quite possible.
3. Syntax elements are essentially regexes. While "Normal" highlight is something used outside of all possible syntax matches. Sort of default. So even if one can build a regex to cover "Normal" highlight, it doesn't seem like a good idea.
4. `:hi` command is always global. `:ownsyntax` allows for a window to have own set of syntax elements, i.e. regexes. But once all groups are matched, their attributes are taken from the global table (except item (1)).

Comment: so the answer for normal vim is 'wincolor' to highlight the background for only one window  ?

Comment: @ritchie Vi/Vim was created as a terminal application. And logically it is still about "character cells", not "GUI background". By default character cells in Vim are painted as "Normal" (or "wincolor").

Comment: I added more info to the question with code....."I am working on an Rgb colors plugin in which I need to be able to look at the random colors. I accomplish by using a popup window with wincolor which seems to to work fine. The colors are not fixed, I just used this dictionary to show as an example. If there are better solutions than mine I would appreciate a response."

Comment: @ritchie Honestly, I just don't understand what's the use of popup windows for you. Open regular window/buffer, create syntax groups and highlights, change it on-the-fly etc. I see no reason to require the whole window to have single color.

Comment: 1. If I want my calendar buffer window background color in gray while my other windows in black I can do that with wincolor. 2. Popup windows are used to look at the different colors that are being generated in my plugin. I can't remember 16 million hex colors, I need to be able to see them to make sure the plugin is working right.

Comment: It's not true that you can't assign arbitrary color to anything, signs exist. [colorscheme - Vim zebra line coloring? - Vi and Vim Stack Exchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/10156/vim-zebra-line-coloring)

Comment: @user202729 "Anything except highlighting group". Signs get colors by linking them to highlighting groups, like everything else.